# How to model unusual shaped tank volume

Tags: geometry

Can anyone advise on an approach for modelling the volume and corresponding levels for the tank shown ? I can obtain specific measurements but was looking for an approach to the problem.

Any help appreciated..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5qKp.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/djrCP.jpg

Comment: Measure your tank, input the data into a computer and use numerical algorithms (integration etc.) to compute the levels. That should be easier than trying to find a nice, geometrical model for a strange, real life object (and the model will be no more exact than the numerical approximation, because your tank is surely not a perfect geometric figure).

Comment: Thanks Dirk, its the algorithms to solve it I was looking for some help with, it will ultimately be modelled in code.

Comment: Could you show numbers (volume vs level) ? What about splines ?

Comment: All I have is the images you see and the ability to take measurements directly when needed. It only needs to be 90% accurate if that helps ?

Comment: Then approximate it with a half-cylinder with two quarter-spheres on the ends.

Comment: Thanks Ivan - thats where I had got to with my simple maths, but I don't know how to calculate those elements in volume, and factor in a level with the tank to come up with a current level. Can you help ?

Comment: Obviously, the volume of a half-cylinder is half that of a cylinder. But if we want to consider variable level, then things get hairy, with arcsine and stuff.

Comment: Yeah its at that point my abilities run out. I'm sure i can code it if someone can explain the formula.